# Why is internal consistency a measure of reliability?

Tags: reliability, methodology, validity

Why is 'internal consistency' a measure of [reliability](https://www.scribbr.com/methodology/types-of-reliability/)? It looks like a measure of [validity](https://www.scribbr.com/methodology/types-of-validity/) instead.

### **Definitions:**

"Internal consistency reflects the extent to which items within an instrument measure various aspects of the same characteristic or construct." [(Revicki, 2014)](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-94-007-0753-5_1494)

"Reliability refers to the extent to which a measure yields the same number or score each time it is administered, all other things being equal" [(Hays & Revicki, 2005)](https://books.google.pl/books?hl=pl&lr=&id=wWRLN5U9-3YC&oi=fnd&pg=PA25&ots=PbUJNFv5-4&sig=P5AcghHTP0b5YicouQGNKfMOQvA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

### **Example:**

Let's assume I've made a **survey A** in which all items measure level of physical activity.
First item: *I love sport*
Second item: *I hate sedentary lifestyle*
**Survey A** has high internal consistency.

Let's assume I've made a **survey B** in which all items measure level of physical activity.
First item: *I love sport*
Second item: *I hate sushi*
**Survey B** has low internal consistency. Hating sushi is a poor measure of physical activity. Therefore, it's the construct validity issue. Reliability, as defined by Hayes & Revicki, won't suffer, because we will expect similar results from similar people.

Comment: (+1) I appreciate that you have provided referenced definitions and examples.